# ¿Cómo activar el modo OnTop en apps UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

No encuentro una Api de la familia w10 que permite eso de poner una ventana/aplicación encima de otra, como que la comunes están pensadas que funcione en todos los dispositivos de la familia Windows 10 (w10 Escritorio, w10 mobil, lot etc..), es por suponer que no hay, ya que en w10m eso no tiene sentido.

Me refiero a usar esa API

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx

¿Cómo puedo usar esa API en la aplicación UWP que solo afecte si está corriendo en Windows 10 Desktop? o bien que soluciones hay al respecto.

**Actualización:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx

> Como parte del núcleo, UWP ahora proporciona una plataforma común de
>   aplicaciones disponible en todos los dispositivos que se ejecutan en
>   Windows 10. Con esta evolución, las aplicaciones destinadas a UWP no
>   solo pueden llamar a las API de WinRT comunes a todos los
>   dispositivos, sino también a las API (incluidas las API de Win32 y.
>   NET) específicas de la familia de dispositivos en los que se ejecuta
>   la aplicación. UWP proporciona un nivel de API principal garantizado
>   en todos los dispositivos.

y por SO me encontrado que se puede usar `SetForegroundWindow`

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
```

¿Cómo se puede cargar la librería `user32.dll` en caso que la app UWP este corriendo en Windows 10 Desktop?

Comment: Creo que no existe nada igual para UWP, no lo he visto, pero deja encontrar algo oficial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qué tal, como tal no se puede hacer lo que quieres, aunque uwp puede usar api win32 solo una parte de estas están disponibles.

Recuerda que las apps uwp son un sandbox por lo tanto aunque ya tiene menos limitaciones que las anteriores de Windows 8.1 aún siguen siendo limitadas.

Actualización:

Aquí la documentación de las Api Win32 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx

Como verás las apps de Windows 10 Universales soportan parte de estas apis.

Las aplicaciones universales tienen restricciones o limitaciones y no pueden hacer muchas cosas que apps tradicionales  Win32  pueden hacer, porque necesitan permisos o no tienen acceso. Así que por el momento lo que quieres hacer no es soportado por las razones que te he dado.

Saludos

Comment: Tu respuesta no es muy clara, podrías agregar mas detalles?

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta saludos

Comment: Gracias, es lo que me temía, que la UWP fuera de sus comunes,me viene de fabula, eso de poder especificar código para cada plataforma.

Answer (score 1):

Debido a la edición de la pregunta esta respuesta esta desactualizada

<s>Hay [un voto](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/11179821-uwp-windows-always-on-top) por característica que buscas en el [foro de Developer Feedback de **Windows Universal Plataform**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform)</s>

Por tanto, parece que no hay forma aun de lograrlo.

Comment: Pero no entiendo, en el párrafo Introducción https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx de las UWP dice que se puede usar apis de win32 pero que solo funcionarán en su determinada familia de dispositivo que la soporte